# Fill in word that letter is located in

Tags: r, nlp, tidyverse

I am processing keystroke data, and need to find the word that a keystroke is located within. Because there can be invisible keystrokes (like Shift) or deleted keystrokes, this is not a trivial problem where I can just iterate the index of keystrokes, and locate the word. Rather, I need to find the space-delimited word that the keystroke is produced within. I do have the full text and existing text available, which I should be able to leverage. I've tried solutions using `fill()`, `lag()`, and `cumsum()`, but none are working.

I have a dataframe like the below, where I group by `experiment_id`:

```
x <- tibble(
  experiment_id = rep(c('1a','1b'),each=12),
  keystroke = rep(c('a','SPACE','SHIFT','b','e','DELETE','a','d','SPACE','m','a','n'),2),
  existing_text = rep(c('a','a ','a ','a B','a Be','a B','a Ba','a Bad','a Bad ',
                    'a Bad m','a Bad ma','a Bad man'),2),
  final_text = 'a Bad man'
)
```

The additional column should look like this, where SPACE belongs to the word it follows, and DELETEs and the deleted keystrokes are part of the final word:

```
within_word = c('a','a','BeDELETEad','BeDELETEad','BeDELETEad','BeDELETEad','BeDELETEad','BeDELETEad','BeDELETEad','man','man','man')
```

Is there a way to derive this?

**EDIT FOR ADDITIONAL HELP:** In the comments below the answer, @Onyambu mentioned that there is a simpler solution using the `keystroke` column. I've found that in my larger, more complex data that `existing_text` is not always reliable. I would strongly prefer a solution that relies on `keystroke` primarily. I've also added in complications due to deletions.

Comment: Could you elaborate more? What do you mean by *space-delimited word that the keystroke is produced within*? Also can you include an example with the shift keystroke

Comment: No problem. Example is updated. A space-delimited word is a word surrounded by spaces.

Comment: so what are you looking for? why should there be NA in teh second element?

Comment: Because a SPACE isn't within a word, it's between words. The desired results are in the 2nd code block above. Thanks!

Comment: cant you just change the keystroke column?ie replace all capitals with NA, then fill upwards leaving 1 NA

Comment: What happens when `SHIFT` is held across **multiple** ensuing keystrokes?  For example, suppose I hold down `SHIFT` without interruption, while typing `a` and then `b`; my results should be `"A"` and `"B"`.  Is this recorded in the `keystroke` column as {`"SHIFT"`, `"a"`, `"SHIFT"`, `"b"`}, which represents a single stroke on `SHIFT` as two separate strokes?  Or is it recorded as {`"SHIFT"`, `"a"`, `"b"`}, which would look identical to the keystrokes above that produced `"A"` and `"b"`?  Or since both these conventions are ambiguous, is there some other method?

Comment: Also, kindly provide a reproducible example of your dataset.  We need to know all "special" keys like `SHIFT` (etc.) that are included, and how they are named (`"SHIFT"`, etc.) in this dataset.

Comment: Frankly, the only way to fully reconstruct keyboard output is to know the sequence in which keys were **depressed** and **released**.  Since some of the keys (like `SHIFT` or `CTRL`) perform functions on subsequent inputs, then a sequence like {`"SHIFT"`, `"a"`, `"b"`} is insufficient; really, we need to represent key depressions (`TRUE`) and releases (`FALSE`) like so: {{`"SHIFT"`, `TRUE`}, {`"a"`, `TRUE`}, {`"a"`, `FALSE`}, {`"b"`, `TRUE`}, {`"b"`, `FALSE`}, {`"SHIFT"`, `FALSE`}}, which is `SHIFT("a", "b")` or alternatively {`"A"`, `"B"`}.

Comment: This is different than {{`"SHIFT"`, `TRUE`}, {`"a"`, `TRUE`}, {`"a"`, `FALSE`}, {`"SHIFT"`, `FALSE`}, {`"b"`, `TRUE`}, {`"b"`, `FALSE`}}, which is {`SHIFT("a")`, `"b"`} or alternatively {`"A"`, `"b"`}.

Comment: Believe it or not, the [**`KeyboardSimulator`**](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/KeyboardSimulator/KeyboardSimulator.pdf) package appears capable of reconstructing such output.

Comment: I will have to check out that package. I do have full keystroke information available from my experiment. I’m just not sure how reliable the timing information is, so I’m making peace with a rough approximation, since I have a lot of data that’ll average things out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below are two approaches:

The first uses the information in `existing_text` only for the grouping and constructs the `within_words` columns based on this grouping and `keystroke`.

The second approach uses only the information in `keystroke`.

---

First approach: grouping based on `existing_text` and content based on `keystroke`:

We take three steps:

First, we caclulate the grouping based on `strsplit` where we look for spaces `\\s` that are preceeded by words `\\w`. We need to correct the values for `"SHIFT"` since they should be counted to the word after `"SPACE"`.

Step two is the replace `"SHIFT"` (and all other similar functions which the example data doesn't contain) with `""`.

Third, we collapse the strings with `paste0(..., collapse = "")`.

```r
library(tidyverse)

x %>%

  # step1: construct grouping:
  mutate(word_grp = lengths(strsplit(existing_text, "(?<=\\w)\\s", perl = TRUE)) %>% 
           if_else(keystroke == "SHIFT", lead(., default = last(.)), .)) %>%
  group_by(experiment_id, word_grp) %>% 

  # step 2 & 3: first replace keys like "SHIFT" with "", the collapse with `paste0`
  mutate(within_word = str_replace_all(keystroke, c("SHIFT" = "", "SPACE" = "")) %>% 
           paste0(., collapse = ""))

#> # A tibble: 24 x 6
#> # Groups:   experiment_id, word_grp [6]
#>    experiment_id keystroke existing_text final_text word_grp within_word
#>    <chr>         <chr>     <chr>         <chr>         <int> <chr>      
#>  1 1a            a         "a"           a Bad man         1 a          
#>  2 1a            SPACE     "a "          a Bad man         1 a          
#>  3 1a            SHIFT     "a "          a Bad man         2 beDELETEad 
#>  4 1a            b         "a B"         a Bad man         2 beDELETEad 
#>  5 1a            e         "a Be"        a Bad man         2 beDELETEad 
#>  6 1a            DELETE    "a B"         a Bad man         2 beDELETEad 
#>  7 1a            a         "a Ba"        a Bad man         2 beDELETEad 
#>  8 1a            d         "a Bad"       a Bad man         2 beDELETEad 
#>  9 1a            SPACE     "a Bad "      a Bad man         2 beDELETEad 
#> 10 1a            m         "a Bad m"     a Bad man         3 man        
#> # … with 14 more rows
```

---

Second approach: based on information in `keystrokes` only.

Here is one approach which only uses the information in `keystroke`. However, if we only want to use the data in `keystroke` things get much more laborious.

Here is a short explanation of the steps taken below:

**Step 1a: data cleaning**
We need to clean the data in `keystrokes` so that they can be used for the new column `within_word`. This means two things: (a) we need to replace every keystroke that should not be printed in `within_word` with `""`. And before this we need to (b) change the leading keystroke based on the function of that key. In the case of `SHIFT` this means we need to set the leading `keystroke` `toupper`. For your example data this is really simple, because there is only `SHIFT` we need to take care of. However, in your real data there might be many similar other keys such as `ALT` or `^`. So we need to repeat Step 1a for each key. Ideally we would come up with a function taking the name of the key and the function that it uses on the leading `keystroke`. Note that we do not yet include `"SPACE"` in this step, since we need it in Step 2.

To see how many keys you need to take care of in your actual data we can filter for those `keystroke`s that don't change the `existing_text`. In your example data this is only `SHIFT`:

```r
# get all keystrokes that don't change the existing_text directly
x %>% 
  select(keystroke, existing_text) %>% 
  filter(existing_text == lag(existing_text, default = ""))

#> # A tibble: 2 x 2
#>   keystroke existing_text
#>   <chr>     <chr>        
#> 1 SHIFT     "a "         
#> 2 SHIFT     "a "
```

**Step 2: create grouping**
We need to create the grouping of the words in `within_text`. This is the most complicated step. Below we first look for rows where `within_word` == `"SPACE"` and which succeeding row is `!= "SPACE"`. We use `data.table::rleid` on the result to get a run-length id for this variable. Finally we need to subtract `1` for those rows which `within_word == "SPACE"`.

**Step 3: data prep before final step**
This is basically similar to step 1a, we need to replace `"SPACE"` with `""` because we don't want it in our result. However, since we needed this column for step 2 we have to finalize the data cleaning in this step.

**Step 4: collapse the strings in `within_word`**
Finally, we group by `experiment_id` and by `word_grp` and collapse the strings in `within_word` with `paste0(..., collapse = "")`.

```r
library(tidyverse)

  # step 1a: data cleaning
  mutate(within_word = if_else(lag(keystroke, default = first(keystroke)) == "SHIFT",
                               toupper(keystroke),
                               keystroke) %>%
                          str_replace_all(., c("SHIFT" = ""))) %>%  
 
  # step 1b to 1n: repeat step 1a for other keys like ALT, ^ etc. 

  # step 2: create groups
  group_by(experiment_id) %>% 
  mutate(word_grp = data.table::rleid(
      within_word == "SPACE" & lead(within_word, default = first(keystroke)) != "SPACE"
    ) %>% if_else(within_word == "SPACE", . - 1L, .)) %>% 

  # step 3: data prep before final step
  ungroup %>% 
  mutate(within_word = str_replace(within_word, "SPACE", "")) %>%
 
  # step 4: collapse
  group_by(experiment_id, word_grp) %>% 
  mutate(within_word = paste0(within_word, collapse = ""))

#> # A tibble: 24 x 6
#> # Groups:   experiment_id, word_grp [6]
#>    experiment_id keystroke existing_text final_text within_word word_grp
#>    <chr>         <chr>     <chr>         <chr>      <chr>          <int>
#>  1 1a            a         "a"           a Bad man  a                  1
#>  2 1a            SPACE     "a "          a Bad man  a                  1
#>  3 1a            SHIFT     "a "          a Bad man  BeDELETEad         3
#>  4 1a            b         "a B"         a Bad man  BeDELETEad         3
#>  5 1a            e         "a Be"        a Bad man  BeDELETEad         3
#>  6 1a            DELETE    "a B"         a Bad man  BeDELETEad         3
#>  7 1a            a         "a Ba"        a Bad man  BeDELETEad         3
#>  8 1a            d         "a Bad"       a Bad man  BeDELETEad         3
#>  9 1a            SPACE     "a Bad "      a Bad man  BeDELETEad         3
#> 10 1a            m         "a Bad m"     a Bad man  man                5
#> # … with 14 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2021-12-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

```
x %>%
  mutate(ww = str_remove(existing_text, fixed(lag(existing_text, default = ".")))) %>%
  group_by(grp = cumsum(ww== ' '|lag(ww == ' ', default = F))) %>%
  mutate(within_word = str_c(ww, collapse = ''),
         within_word = na_if(within_word, ' '))

# A tibble: 10 x 6
# Groups:   grp [5]
   keystroke existing_text final_text ww      grp within_word
   <chr>     <chr>         <chr>      <chr> <int> <chr>      
 1 a         "a"           a Bad man  "a"       0 a          
 2 SPACE     "a "          a Bad man  " "       1 NA         
 3 SHIFT     "a "          a Bad man  ""        2 Bad        
 4 b         "a B"         a Bad man  "B"       2 Bad        
 5 a         "a Ba"        a Bad man  "a"       2 Bad        
 6 d         "a Bad"       a Bad man  "d"       2 Bad        
 7 SPACE     "a Bad "      a Bad man  " "       3 NA         
 8 m         "a Bad m"     a Bad man  "m"       4 man        
 9 a         "a Bad ma"    a Bad man  "a"       4 man        
10 n         "a Bad man"   a Bad man  "n"       4 man
```

Comment: Could you please explain your code? It's pretty dense.

Comment: @Adam_G where exactly ? Well before I go down this lane, are we supposed to use the Keystroke column? In this answer, I did not use it

Comment: Use the keystroke column for what? I'm not sure I understand your question.

Comment: I should also add that this answer does appear to be correct. However, I don't understand how `fixed()`, grouping by a `cumsum()`,the single pipe operator, or `str_c()` work.

Comment: @Adam_G I ignored the Keystroke column. But if we can use it to come up with the within word, then it would be much simpler. So far, I only used the existing text column to come up with the within word column

Comment: @Adam. `fixed` ensures that if the text contains `?, ., -, [], () + , *` they should be considered literal as they are and not to have a different meaning since they are metacharacters in regex

Comment: @Adam_G try running each line at a time to see what happens. Do not run the whole pipe. Run the first two then the first 3 etc. In that case, you can see what happens

Comment: Thanks so much for all of these explanations! Really helpful! Just one more (probably trivial) problem. I had already grouped my data, and this code seems to not work within those groups. I've modified the code to reflect the initial grouping, `experiment_id`.

Comment: @Adam_G whats the question

Comment: The code doesn't work when it's run within a group. I didn't think that was relevant, but when I ran it, it's not resetting the cumsum, but carrying it over across groups.

Comment: @Adam_G in that case, take the `grp = .. ` within the groupby, to the `mutate` function before, then do `group_by(grp, .add = TRUE)`

Comment: @Adam_G that code can only work in the case when the data is grouped. so cannot really modify as it will be solving a different issue altogether. What I am trying to say is that, `x %>% mutate(maintain everything here, grp = copy grp from groupby function)%>%group_by(grp, .add = TRUE)%>%...`

Comment: Thanks. I appreciate the solution. It does work but it would be really helpful to comment the code and use more intuitive variable names.

Comment: @Adam_G am sorry about that. Hope you understood the code though

Comment: I'm having some trouble with this on complex groups, which I'll work on debugging. You had mentioned in a previous comment that you have a simple solution using the Keystroke column. By any chance do you remember what that looked like?